# SDL+OpenGL program not appearing on linux

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, sdl

I started making this super simple game engine with SDL and OpenGL on windows. The Engine is in a static lib and the so far all it does is display a blue window, with all the ground work for an engine.

It ran fine on Windows but then I ported it to Linux and nothing. The program runs fine and is shown in the system monitor but no window is appearing. I installed a couple of mesa and gl libs to check that wasn't it. Now it wont run and says process terminated with status -1.

This is the initialization code in the engine. Please ask for anything else.

```
#include "Scales.h"
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "gl.h"
#include "glu.h"

Engine *scalesEngine;

bool OnInit(int WindowHeight, int WindowWidth){

    SDL_Surface* Surf_Display;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
        return false;
   }
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE,        8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE,      8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE,       8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE,      8);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE,      16);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE,        32);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_RED_SIZE,    8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_GREEN_SIZE,    8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_BLUE_SIZE,    8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCUM_ALPHA_SIZE,    8);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS,  1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES,  2);

   if((Surf_Display = SDL_SetVideoMode(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER | SDL_OPENGL)) = NULL){
        return false;
   }

   glClearColor(0.422f,0.576f,1.0f,1.0f);
   glClearDepth(1.0f);

   glViewport(0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();

   glOrtho(0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0, 1, -1);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

   glLoadIdentity();

   game_Init();

   return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    scalesEngine = new Engine;

    game_preload();

    if(OnInit(scalesEngine->WindowHeight(), scalesEngine->WindowWidth()) == false){
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Event Event;

    //Main Game Loop
    while(scalesEngine->Running){

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)){
            scalesEngine->OnEvent(&Event);
        }


        scalesEngine->Update();
        scalesEngine->Render();
    }

    scalesEngine->OnCleanUp();
    delete scalesEngine;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not get a window, I would suspect that you are not getting your hardware context.  Try using `SDL_SWSURFACE` instead of `SDL_HWSURFACE`.

```
SDL_SetVideoMode(... SDL_SWSURFACE ...
```

I've seen this happen when developing in a VM, though I'm sure there are other reasons.

edit:

As noted in the comments, both of these surface flags may be superfluous along with `SDL_OPENGL` anyway.

Comment: I would drop the flag entirely. You don't need to worry about that surface flag when making an OpenGL context instead of a raw drawing surface.

Comment: Actually SDL_HWSURFACE, SDL_SWSURFACE and SDL_OPENGL are mutually exclusive. You can pick only one of them.

Comment: @datenwolf: Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @datenwolf I vaguely remember using the SDL_OPENGL flag with both of these options on differing platforms.  I would believe that it is just not enforced or ignored, though I cannot find evidence online.

Comment: @TomKerr: Those flags actually make only sense if you want direct access to a "dumb" framebuffer, which can be accessed by memory writed and reads. This is called a surface. OpenGL operations don't involve such kinds of framebuffer access and may not be supported by the OpenGL implementation at all. Remember that SDL started without OpenGL support. That was added only later.

Comment: @datenwolf I don't doubt you are correct; I just cannot find anything online that explains it.  I have converted the answer to a community wiki.  Please clarify anything you would.

Answer (score 3):

```
if((Surf_Display = SDL_SetVideoMode(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER | SDL_OPENGL)) = NULL){
    return false;
}
```

I'm pretty sure you meant `== NULL`, right?